# Setting Cookie Expiration time.

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have the following script that is for a popup on my home page.  It works well except the cookie seems to reset its self every day.  I would like for the cookie to expire as far into the future as possible.   My problem is that i am new to javascript and cookies within.  Can someone let me know what part i need to change?  I have messed with some of it but seem to be making it worse.

As it sits on my site (http://www.swissdiamond.us)  You can see that it is working (loads the div the first time you are there, and not any other) but if you come back tomorrow the hidden div will re-load.

Thanks for any help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
  var c = ca[i];
  while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
  if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}
return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

 function showModal() {
tb_show('Newsletter Signup','#TB_inline?height=300&amp;width=450&amp;inlineId=promo',false);
}

var visited = readCookie('mypopup');

 if (!visited) {
$(document).ready(function(){
  showModal();
  createCookie('mypopup','no',0);
});
}

//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update this line

```
 date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
```

Or you can pass days value from here

```
createCookie('mypopup','no',0); // make the last parameter value as much as you want
```

Here you can add more days as you want. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your `createCookie` function sets the expiry for you, however you are passing `0` as the days value to expire, so the cookie does not persist. Try this:

```
createCookie('mypopup', 'no', 7); // 7 = expires in 7 days, amend as required.
```